# Manhwa where the protagonist has no mana and rely on physical strength. Also the story is about team fights (like DOTA) but real people fightning

Tags: story-identification, manga

Manhwa where the protagonist has no mana and rely on physical strength. Also the story is about team fights (like DOTA) but real people fighting

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! I'm not really sure this is enough for us to go on. Is there anything else you remember about this manga - what the protagonist's name was, what they looked like, what the purpose of these "team fights" was? Anything at all?

Comment: Did he carry an iron "wand" that he reshapes into various weapons to fight with?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're thinking of *[Mashle: Magic and Muscles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashle)*?

> Set in a magical world in which an individual's position within society are defined by the power and skill with magic, Mash Burnedead is a young man without so much as an ounce of magic in his blood. In order to live a peaceful life with his adoptive father, Regro, Mash will need to become a Divine Visionary (神覚者, Shinkakusha), a title which is only given to exceptional students from the Easton Magic Academy. Despite having no magic whatsoever, Mash goes to the magic school, determined to survive and show the world that muscles can beat magic.

I haven't read it myself, but the references indicate frequent battles/duels within the school and with other schools.

It's a manga, not a manhwa, though.